# Filter ng-repeat results using an id variable stored in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an id in my controller, let's say `id = 1`, and a list of data items `$scope.items = data`. 
The data structure looks like this :

```
"data": [ {
         "id":1,
         "name":"ranjith"
     },
     {
        "id":2,
        "name":"sumanth"
     }
]
```

My HTML

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items | filter: getResult">{{item.name}}</span>
```

`getResult` in my controller:

```
$scope.getResult = function(a){ if (a.id== $scope.id) return true; else return false; }
```

I want to output only the item with `id=1` means the data set with `id=1` and `name=ranjith`. I tried some codes but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you provide what you've tried ? Like the content of your filter `getResult`

Comment: $scope.getResult = function(a){

            if (a.id== $scope.id)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }

Comment: and when you say *nothing seems to work*, do you mean it outputs nothing, or it outputs everything?

Comment: `<span ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {id: id}"</span>` would be sufficient 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Aw6g4ixhdWPKt2Co1xRn?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to getting it working, but there are several errors:

- You didn't close your `span` properly,
- You didn't output anything in your `span`, so you won't see a thing if it works
- You store your dataset in a var called `data`, and then use `items` in your `ng-repeat`

Your code should at least look like this :

```js
var app = angular.module("fiddle", []);

app.controller("fiddle_controller",   function($scope){
  $scope.items = [
    {
         "id":1,
         "name":"ranjith"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"sumanth"
    }
  ];
  $scope.id = 1;

  $scope.getResult = function(item){
      return item.id == $scope.id;
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fiddle">
  <div ng-controller="fiddle_controller">
    <span ng-repeat="item in items | filter: getResult">
      {{item.name}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oops! my mistake. i will never repeat this. Sorry for taking your valuable time. @zamarrowski

Comment: @Ranjith No problem, glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In html:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in data | filter: getResult">{{item}}</span>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.data =  [ { "id":1, "name":"ranjith" }, { "id":2, "name":"sumanth" } ];
$scope.id = 1;
//Filter
$scope.getResult = function(item){
    return item.id == $scope.id;
};
```